# Read .NET Control "Design" properties at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

How do you read out the .NET Windows.Forms "Design" properties at runtime? (I assume it must be possible, as Designers etc. are using them.) The "Design" properties are the `GenerateMember`, `Locked` and `Modifiers`.

Eg. I want to read the `Modifiers` property at runtime. If the control is marked as "public", I'll attach a tooltip to it. Or whatever.

Comment: They are not real properties of control. So you can not see them at runtime.

Comment: I guess it would be necessary to write a custom designer inheriting from `ControlDesigner` (using `System.Windows.Forms.Design`) and then starting a "non-interactive design session" (no idea how to do this, therefore its a comment). also, no idea *why* to do this :) ?

Comment: They are implemented by the control designer.  And thus don't exist at runtime.  Tooltips like that are just not useful, it takes a programmer to type in helpful text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Locked` property is added by `ControlDesigner` and `Modifiers` and `GenerateMember` are added by `ModifiersExtenderProvider` just at design time.

They are not real properties of control and they are just useful for designer support and the default serializer doesn't generate any code about them and therefor you can not see them at runtime.

For example `Locked` doesn't have any meaning for runtime.

About knowing if the control has a member and if the member is public or not, you can rely on reflection.

**Example**

```
public bool IsMemberGenerated(string name)
{
    var field = this.GetType().GetField(name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    return field != null;
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant Didn't get your point :\. I'm getting both publics and non-publics. Some controls have members generated and the member can be public or non-public.